# Parallel Detail Sections in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to know that how to make a crystal report such that its details section should display values of details in multiple/parallel fashion depending upon its column value.

Suppose that my data-set for report is as follows,

[image: Sample Data]

I want to group by my report on `Id` and want to display their `Value` in detail section so that if value is positive then it should display in left side and if it is negative then it should display in right side. But these two sides should be "Parallel" in display like this

[image: Reuirement]

Currently if I suppress a field on some condition then it remains blank or when I do "Format with Multiple Columns" then also the required result is not possible. Because In multiple columns option, it is not necessary that my positive's & negatives columns are equal in count, and there is chance to display positive values in negative side.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no logical connection to enforce what values should be on the same row, you probably need to implement this as 2 subreports placed side by side. One to show negative values and one to show positive values. 
The subreports would be placed in the Group Footer for ID and would be linked on ID.